# How to find the cartesian equation of a plane given the vector equation?

Tags: vectors

The vector equation is given by $r=\begin{pmatrix}-3\\ -5\\ -1\end{pmatrix}+k\begin{pmatrix}6\\ 6\\ -3\end{pmatrix}$

To find the cartesian equation, I have to consider a point  on the plane:

$$\begin{pmatrix}x\\ y\\ z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-3\\ -5\\ -1\end{pmatrix}+k\begin{pmatrix}6\\ 6\\ -3\end{pmatrix}$$

which gives:

$$\frac{x+3}{\:6}=\:\frac{y+5}{6}=\frac{z+1}{-3}$$

Now this is the part where I don't understand. Up till now my working follows with the answers provided by my book, but then the book did something that puzzle me:

$$\frac{x+3}{6}+\frac{y+5}{6}=2(\frac{z+1}{-3})$$

How did they reached here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $$\frac{x+3}{6}=\frac{z+1}{-3}$$ and $$\frac{y+5}{6}=\frac{z+1}{-3}$$

Now add these two equations.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation the answer is $x+y+4z+12=0$ right? somehow my textbook gave that it is $x+y-4z+12=0$

Comment: Yes you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

We have that

- $x=-3+6k \implies k=\frac{x+3}6$
- $y=-5+6k\implies k=\frac{y+5}6$
- $z=-1-3k\implies k=-\frac{z+1}3$

therefore

$$\frac{x+3}6+\frac{y+5}6=2k=-2\frac{z+1}3$$

moreover

$$\frac{x+3}6-\frac{y+5}6=2k=0$$

and the given line can be represented, in cartesian form, by the intersection of the two planes

- $x+y+4z+12=0$
- $x-y-2=0$

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you did not report the whole question.

This solution gives the equation of *some* plane that contains the given line. Indeed,

$$a=b=c\implies a+b=2c,$$ but there are infinitely many other combinations, like

$$a=b=c\implies 7a-6b=c$$ or $$a=b=c\implies a=b,$$

all giving planes.

Comment: Ya I did not, the question asks for whether a point $T$ is inside, outside or on the surface of the cylinder. The cylinder as the rotational axis of the equation demonstrated above

Comment: @Nhoj_Gonk What cylinder? There could be an infinitely long cylinder around an axis and no planes would be necessary to decide whether a point is inside or outside. If the cylinder is finite and closed by a circular disk at the end of the cylinder, then a plane perpendicular to the axis is useful to know about, but I do not think the calculation you showed is finding such a plane. I think it will be very difficult to guess what the book is doing unless you show a  lot more of what it actually said.

Comment: @DavidK Hey man thanks for thoughtful comment! Should I update to include the full question?

Comment: @Nhoj_Gonk I see a couple of options, neither ideal: edit the question to include the full question from the book (and probably make these answers mostly obsolete), or ask the full question as a new question (thereby having two questions when you really only wanted the answer to one). I'm leaning toward editing this question. (If you ask a new question I'd say to link back to this question, just to forestall someone saying "Didn't you just ask this question already?")